# How to sanitize PHP posted in comments by users

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am creating a commenting system where users can post comments that can also consist of basic HTML including code. Like this:

```
<pre><code class="language-php"><?php
echo 'Test';
?></code></pre>
```

The problem is that I can't sanitize this one server side because the PHP code in the comment will actually run on my server. I tried using JavaScript like this before submitting the form:

```
$("#comment").val() = $("#comment").val().replace("<?", "&lt;?").replace("?>", "?&gt;");
```

However, this results in Syntax error.

Is there any way for me to safely post user comments that consist of PHP?

Comment: I am not entirely sure that the code will actually run on my server. It is just a guess because the server will actually be parsing it as PHP and not a code snippet. :)

Comment: You should never trust javascript to sanitize input. A user can easily disable javascript.

Comment: However, everytime I tested this with PHP code inside the `code` tags. There was an error.

Comment: @PressingOnAlways Is there some other way to safely show the PHP code?

Comment: @VineetSharma always sanitize/validate server-side, user might have disabled JS and your front-side validation won't trigger. User might also skip/disable FS validation

Comment: @PaulCrovella I think so because the server keeps giving me errors. However, as soon as I change `<?` to `< ?`. The errors stop and the comments get  posted. As far as I know, that happened because the server stopped parsing the code snippet as PHP. I may be wrong though. :)

Comment: How are you storing and retrieving the comments, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: could you not use `htmlentities` to safely convert all applicable characters to a safe form for storage or is that not what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

to set a new value of input element using jquery, you need to use this syntax

```
$("#yourElement").val(newValue);
```

so change your javascript code to:

```
$("#comment").val($("#comment").val().replace("<?", "&lt;?").replace("?>", "?&gt;"));
```

read: http://api.jquery.com/val/